# Google Tag Manager trigger for previous page referrer not working

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I need to trigger a tag when previous page referrer includes certain text.
E.g. if hostname/about was previous page than it should trigger.

For now I've created Page view trigger that is triggered when Referrer matches regex `\/about\/`.

It should add a tag that adds JavaScript and HTML to the page.
However, in preview mode I can see that this Page view trigger doesn't trigger.

Comment: Can you provide any more information/screenshots? In theory your set up should work.

Comment: The problem was that I misunderstood referrer and was trying to match it in the beginning of string when it of course doesn't match.